# Jquery, работа с вновь подгруженным контентом

Tags: jquery

Есть блок cat-link, по нажатию на который срабатывает скрипт. Нажатие на кнопку >Показать ещё...< добавляет еще n-е количество блоков cat-link. Вопрос, как оптимизировать скрипт, что бы он срабатывал на вновь добавленные блоки cat-link?
Саму кнопку >Показать ещё...< редактировать нельзя.

```
<div class="cat-link shop-item-foto" rel="https://mirtechniki.net"><i class="icon-image i-shop-item-foto"></i><div сlass="text-itempage-foto">Смотреть</div></div>

<div id="shop-page-more" class=""><button onclick="shopPageMore({more:shop_page+1})">Показать ещё...</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('.cat-link').click(function(){window.open($(this).attr('rel') );}); });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел решение, оказалось все довольно-таки просто, использовал [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) вместо `.click()`, кому интересно смотрите код скрипта:

```
$(function($) {
  $(".cat-link").live('click', function() {
    window.open($(this).attr("rel"));
  });
});
```

Comment: deprecated v.1.7, removed 1.9  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: лучше использовать $("body").on('click', '.cat-link', function...)